# What does the class look like that is returned from WP_User_Query?

Tags: author, list-authors

```
$wp_user_search = new WP_User_Query( array( 'role' => 'author' ) );
$author_list = $wp_user_search->get_results();

foreach($author_list as $author)
{
  // author properties?
}
```

Can you point me in the direction of the documentation of what properties `$author` has?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either an array of row objects with properties the column names of the result of the SQL query - ie. the specified fields from the wp_users table or, if fields equals 'all_with_meta', an array of WP_User objects.

The fields value defaults to 'all', which will return all the columns in the [wp_users table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_users_2), but can be overridden by passing an array of specified fields - and is parsed as follows:

```
              if ( is_array( $qv['fields'] ) ) {
                        $qv['fields'] = array_unique( $qv['fields'] );

                        $this->query_fields = array();
                        foreach ( $qv['fields'] as $field )
                                $this->query_fields[] = $wpdb->users . '.' . esc_sql( $field );
                        $this->query_fields = implode( ',', $this->query_fields );
                } elseif ( 'all' == $qv['fields'] ) {
                        $this->query_fields = "$wpdb->users.*";
                } else {
                        $this->query_fields = "$wpdb->users.ID";
                }
```

see the query function in the [WP_User_Query class definition](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/user.php) - where the query results is replaced with WP_User objects if 'fields' is 'all_with_meta'

```
       function query() {
                global $wpdb;

                if ( is_array( $this->query_vars['fields'] ) || 'all' == $this->query_vars['fields'] ) {
                        $this->results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT $this->query_fields $this->query_from $this->query_where $this->query_orderby $this->query_limit");
                } else {
                        $this->results = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT $this->query_fields $this->query_from $this->query_where $this->query_orderby $this->query_limit");
                }

                if ( $this->query_vars['count_total'] )
                        $this->total_users = $wpdb->get_var( apply_filters( 'found_users_query', 'SELECT FOUND_ROWS()' ) );

                if ( !$this->results )
                        return;

                if ( 'all_with_meta' == $this->query_vars['fields'] ) {
                        cache_users( $this->results );

                        $r = array();
                        foreach ( $this->results as $userid )
                                $r[ $userid ] = new WP_User( $userid, '', $this->query_vars['blog_id'] );

                        $this->results = $r;
                }
        }
```

And finally, the WP_User object is documented here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User

and defined here: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/capabilities.php

Comment: Ever tried [this](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/3.2) link? Linkin is easier than posting :)

Comment: @Kailser The link doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry - realized it was a bit ridiculous and revised the answer.  Also corrected it. It sometimes returns WP_User objects.

Comment: Took the opportunity to update the codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query -- please feel free to improve on my efforts there.

Comment: @marfarma The link works for me and takes you to wp source on wp trac. About the Codex edit: Always rocks when people step in :)

Answer (score 1):

Do the following to the foreach loop:

```
echo '<pre>';
foreach($author_list as $author)
{
    // author properties:
    // in detail:
    var_dump($author);
    // OR: overview:
    print_r($author);
}
echo '</pre>';
```